# What does O( n^{1+o(1)} ) mean

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-classes

The latest development in solving the [max-flow problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem#Algorithms) promises a ${\displaystyle O(E^{1+o(1)}\log U)}$ solution.

What does it mean, this $O(n^{1+o(1)})$-complexity?

Comment: In other communities, I see it spelled: "$O(n^{1+\epsilon})$ for all $\epsilon>0$".

Comment: It _usually_ means people are playing games with constants to make things look better than they are </cynic>. (Where that o(1) "actually" means "for any $\epsilon > 0$ you can come up with an algorithm with $n^{1 + \epsilon}$ scaling... but with a correspondingly-galactic constant factor.) I don't know about this case however. Hopefully it's better.

Comment: @TLW I don't think the constant factor could scale too fast because there needs to be _one_ algorithm that satisfies $n^{1+\varepsilon}$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$. If each $\varepsilon$ may have a different algorithm then you can diagonalize to get a single algorithm, but if the constant factor grows fast enough as $\varepsilon$ shrinks then the diagonalization doesn't satisfy $n^{1+o(1)}$.

Comment: That accurately sums up the games I alluded to, yes - "for any $\epsilon>0$ you can come up with an algorithm with $\text{O}(n^{k+\epsilon})$ scaling" is subtly different from (and insufficient to show) $\text{O}(n^{k+\text{o}(1)})$ scaling. See e.g. https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/9186/definition-of-matrix-multiplication-exponent-omega

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function $f(n)$ is $O(n^{1+o(1)})$ if there exist a constant $C > 0$ and a function $g(n)$ satisfying $\lim_{n\to\infty} g(n) = 0$ such that
$$ f(n) \leq Cn^{1+g(n)}. $$

Answer (score 1):

As n grows, o(1) eventually becomes less than 1, then less than 1/2, then less than 1/3 and so on.

So as n gets large, f(n) will be O(n ^ 3/2), O(n ^ 4/3) and so on. The factor between n and f(n) can become larger and larger, but the increase will become less.